# PCA for feature extraction MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pca

I have a data matrix `A` of size `N-by-M`.
I wanted use `PCA` for dimensionality reduction. I want to set the dimensions to '`k`'.

I understand that after feature extraction, I should get a Nxk matrix.

I have tried `pcares` as follows,

```
[residuals,reconstructed] = pcares(A,k)
```

But this does not help me.

I am also trying to use the dr toolbox ([here](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/Matlab_Toolbox_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.html))
This returns me a `k-by-k` matrix. How do I proceede further?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Please explain why the output of `pcares` does not help you.

Comment: I do not understand the output of pcares.
it gives me a NxM matrix as my approximation after dimensionality reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pcares` gives you the residual, which is the error when subtracting the input with the reconstructed input. You can use the `pca` command. It returns a `MxM` matrix whose columns are the principle components. You can use the first `k` of them to construct the feature, just do the following

`X = bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A)) * coeff(:, 1:k);`, where `coeff` is what is returned from the `pca` command. The function call with `bsxfun` subtracts the mean (centers the data, as this is what `pca` did when calculating the output `coeff`).